# PyQt5 : State_MouseOver in QStyledItemDelegate just inside QtableView

Tags: python, pyqt5, qstyleditemdelegate

Sorry, I couldn't think of a better title.

I have a QStyledItemDelegate that sets the MousePointer to QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor when I hover over column 8. The problem is that when I exit column 8 above the table header, the cursor remains QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor, but my thought was that the cursor should be restored by QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor().

My delegate:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore

class reportDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(reportDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)

        if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_MouseOver:
            if option.index.column() == 8 and option.index.row() >=0:
                if option.text:
                    QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
                else:
                    QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
            else:
                QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that, and it won't work for three reasons:

1. in your implementation, the `restoreOverrideCursor()` only happens when the option state is "under mouse";
2. delegates are only "triggered" for *existing* items, if the mouse has to change cursor, that has to happen no matter if the mouse is over a valid index (or, better, a valid index with a delegate) or not;
3. `setOverrideCursor()` is *application-wide*, but for a case such as this you should only set the cursor for the widget, especially because
   [`setOverrideCursor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#setOverrideCursor) use an internal *stack* of cursors, so if you call `setOverrideCursor()` twice and `restoreOverrideCursor()` only once, the "original" cursor won't be restored;

This clearly means one thing: the implementation cannot happen in the delegate, but in the view, and it should set the cursor for the view (or, to be precise, its *viewport*), not for the application.

Since Qt item views normally accept hover events, the solution is quite simple: override the view's [`event()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#event) and react to `HoverMove` events:

```py
class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == event.HoverMove:
            index = self.indexAt(self.viewport().mapFromParent(event.pos()))
            if index.column() == 7:
                self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
            else:
                self.viewport().unsetCursor()
        return super().event(event)
```

This can also be achieved for views created within Designer, either by installing an event filter *or* by using a promoted widget. Please do some research on those subjects to understand how to achieve that.

Comment: I actually solved it in the meantime with an event filter. i thought the delegate was responsible for such things though, so i wasn't sure. However, `HoverMove` doesn't work for me. I use `MouseMove` to make it work. Thank you very much

Comment: @Robert It's possible that the hover event is only implemented in some situations; try implementing the above in `viewportEvent()` (or by installing the filter for the view's `viewport()`): using HoverMove is usually a preferred choice than MouseMove for these situations. Besides, if you found an alternate solution on your own, you should post it as your own answer.